# How to break Jmeter test cycle if first test assertion failed?

Tags: java, performance, jmeter, load, performance-testing

I would like to skip further tests in this test cycle if Assertion failed.
In Response Assertion simple string in TextResponse. It is logical to skip test scenario if login is failed, so it should be easy.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. In the Thread group, Select "**Stop Thread**" under **Action to be taken after a sampler error**.
2. you can configure a Response assertion at root level with "Response Code" > "Equals" radio & "Not" checkbox > "200" pattern
   so anything if not 200 will stop the execution.

Answer (score 1):

1. Add [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/six-tips-for-jmeter-if-controller-usage) after the Sampler which you suppose to be failing
2. Use the following [__jexl3() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3) as the condition:

   ```
   ${__jexl3(!${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok},)}
   ```

   it means that If Controller's children will only be executed if the previous Sampler wasn't successful
3. Add [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) sampler as a child of the If Controller and there you will have the choice of:

   - Start Next Thread Loop
   - Break Current Loop
   - Go to next iteration of Current Loop
   - Stop the test
   - Forcefully stop the test

Example test plan outline:

[image]